# Eliminating Prior Calculation Address in VBA Function

Tags: vba, function

Have a simple problem with trying to simplify the code and use in a VBA function for calculating Exponential Moving Average (EMA). Current code is as follows:

```
'Exponential Moving Average
Function nEMA(Price, Periods, nEMA1)
'Variables
Alpha = (2 / (Periods + 1))

'Formula Calculation
nEMA = (Alpha * Price) + ((1 - Alpha) * nEMA1)

End Function
```

I would like to eliminate the prior calculation input "nEMA1."  This solution has a wide range of other application functions, as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will use the value in the same column and one row above the cell it is written in instead of `nEMA1`

```
'Exponential Moving Average
Function nEMA(Price, Periods)
'Variables
Alpha = (2 / (Periods + 1))

'Formula Calculation
' Uses the value above the formula in the calculation
nEMA = (Alpha * Price) + ((1 - Alpha) * Application.Caller.Offset(-1))

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought. but the prior value is needed in the calculation.  I just want to reference it relative to nEMA, not actually select it as input.

Comment: The nEMA1 variable is normally one (1) row above the Function output and is the value of the 1 period earlier calculation. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thank for the response. Very helpful.